# Use grep (or anything) to find keywords lead by a symbol then output comma-separated

Tags: unix, find, grep, design-patterns

I'm attempting to migrate a bunch of my data from one webservice to another, and in the process I want to make sure I do it right so I won't be obsessing about something not being right or out of place.

One of the things I want to do is find words lead by a poundsign within a single file, then extract the word immediately following them, and then print them back comma-separated.

So for example, at some points in the file there'll be "#word - #word2 : #word3" - with completely random stuff between them, mind you, - And then I'd like to be able to kick that back out as

words='word,word2,word3'

ditching the poundsign and any other gibberish around them.

I'm completely useless at anything beyond basic scripting.  Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try:

```
grep -o "#[^ ]*" file | tr -d '#' | tr '\n' ','
```

Comment: That's a good start. What I end up with on most of the files I'm running this on is the data I'm looking for plus about 15 entries I'm not.  It's my fault for not thinking to mention these are HTML files, so every ID, color code, etc. is preceded by a hashtag.  The common link for the data I'm looking for though is that it's always followed by a closing anchor tag, so the pattern I'm looking for is actually #word</a>.

Comment: grep -o "#[^ ]*</a>" file | tr -d '#' | tr '\n' ','
seems to do the trick on an initial test; I'll report back shortly after a few more test runs.

Comment: Just ran into a nasty side effect while trying to ditch the closing anchor; grep -o "#[^ ]*</a>" file | tr -d '#' | tr -d '</a>' | tr '\n' ',' ends up removing the letter 'a' from any search results.

Comment: Bingo. I'm not sure if my circumstance requires removing the trailing comma, but is that an easy tweak?

Comment: To remove trailing comma: `| sed 's/,$//'`

Comment: So far so good. I'm gonna do a test run uploading the data overnight to see how it translates but I think this is exactly what I needed!  Thanks! I just wish I could upvote you.